# How do I make this material-ui card auto size width to fit the page while maintaining a maxHeight

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have one image being displayed inside of a card and I am trying to keep a maximum height while having the width auto size to fit the display. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
wwwusnews_root: {
        width: 'auto',
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(17),

    },
    wwwusnews_media: {
        maxHeight: 640,
        backgroundColor: '#d8d8d8',
        //src: {usnews}
    }
```

```
<Card className={classes.wwwusnews_root}>
            <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.wwwusnews_media}
                    image={usnews}
                    title="Students in masks"
                />
            </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
```

Comment: width `auto` will not fit the size of the display; it will change the width of the element to expand or shrink based on the content inside the element. To have the width fit the display, use `width: '100%'`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Jake B. yes and I don't think material-ui uses 100% as a variable, I see that width: 1; is the equivalent but I must be doing something incorrect

Comment: Can you attach an image of view you want?

Comment: I mean your expected output...It is better, if you can upload your current output as well..

Comment: @mjm, the style you are applying is a CSS class property not a variable; you should be able to set the width value to anything you like; but, I could be wrong if this is documented somewhere else in the API